# Not able to track current user in flask-login in Stripe Webhook

Tags: flask, webhooks, stripe-payments

I am trying to track the current customer and linking the webhook details to the email id of the user.

models.py

```
from flask_login import UserMixin
from . import db

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True) # primary keys are required by SQLAlchemy
    #admin=db.Column
    public_id=db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100))
    name = db.Column(db.String(1000))
```

main.py

```
@main.route("/webhook", methods=["POST"])
def webhooks():
    payload = request.get_data(as_text=True)
    
    sig_header = request.headers.get("Stripe-Signature",None)
    
    

    try:
        event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(
            payload,
            sig_header, stripe_keys["endpoint_secret"]
        )

    except ValueError as e:
        # Invalid payload
        print("Invalid payload")
        return "Invalid payload", 400
    except stripe.error.SignatureVerificationError as e:
        return "Invalid signature", 400

    if current_user.is_authenticated:
                 email=current_user.email
    else:
                  print("Not authenticated!")
```

And it keeps printing "Not authenticated!" In case i use @login_required for webhook endpoint, i keep getting 302 error.

Please enlighten me on where i am going wrong

Comment: The user must be logged in.  Where is the code for the user logging in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`current_user.is_authenticated` is non-sense, because the POST is signed (it's a public route). The problem is the `payload` which you send to the API before the webhook is even being triggered. Add array `metadata` and into there the `user_id`. Then the resulting webhook will also have the `metadata` ... and the `metadata` has the `user_id`. There is no other way to know about any `user_id` in that situation, as the as no user present.

Comment: Thanks a lot! this makes a lot of sense!